# Django how to shuffle a queryset without speed lose

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I want to shuffle a list of objects without losing any speed in terms of optimization and performance speed.
let's say I have the following query.

```
related_products = Announcement.objects.filter(category=category).exclude(id=announcement.id)
```

pythonically, i would import the **random** module and then `random.shuffle(related_products)`. But I am not sure if it will store something in the memory on my view or use some CPU speed or whatever terminology I don't know.

So I wonder what's the best way to make it optimized.

Thanks!

Comment: It will definitely store the products in memory and then will shuffle them. You can use [`.order_by('?')`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) but as stated in the docs, it may cause performance issues

Answer (score 1):

If the list of related_products objects is reasonably short and if you are going to be using them all in any case, It's simplest to just fetch them and then shuffle them.

```
import random
...

products = random.shuffle( list( related_products) )
for product in products:
    ...
```

This is efficient, in that no objects are copied. The main issue is if it's possible that the quantity is excessive. You can use `related_products.count()` to find out how many there are, before fetching any from the DB.

There's also queryset `.order_by('?')` which retrieves in random order, but the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) says "Note: order_by('?') queries may be expensive and slow, depending on the database backend you’re using."

A third possibility for sampling would be to fetch just the primary keys of every row in the table. Shuffle and slice those to get a sample of the required size, then fetch just those objects.

```
product_pks = related_products.values_list('pk', flat=True)
sampled_pks = random.shuffle( list(product_pks))[:N_SAMPLE]
products = related_products.filter( pk__in = sampled_pks )
```

No idea how this would perform, but it's two DB queries and the first fetches the minimum amount of data necessary  for shuffling.

Comment: let's suppose I am using postgresql. will it be slow for shuffling?

Comment: @HTML I don't know, have never needed it. If you have django-ddt installed, you can see what queries got executed and what they cost. I'd have thought the main usage case might be randomizing the order and then slicing to fetch a random sample of the objects ... if that actually works and is tolerably efficient!

Comment: @HTML Also if the queryset has a huge number of records in it, you can consider limiting it.

Comment: @HTML added another idea I just though of.

Comment: isn't ```random``` evaluates the queryset? it means it takes some power to keep data in memory